# NSScrollView can't scroll

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am not that familiar with cocoa ,
I think I missing some simple method call or something.
So my problem is:
I have a subclass that drawing a plot , when I have to draw several plots I putting them inside `NSScrollView`'s `documentView`. 
But here I have a problem When i want to scroll and mouse is on 1 of the plots, it just doesn't scroll , however if my mouse is near the plot (still on `documentView`) everything works fine .

I guess i have to add something inside my subclass so it will tell the `NSScrollView` to scroll , but I have no idea what. could some1 help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are subclassing, the first thing I would check is that you're calling the super implementation in any overridden methods.  Failing to do so is frequently the cause of lost behavior.

Also make sure your plot is not eating the scroll events before they propagate up to the scroll view.

Comment: I am using corePlot to draw Plot , does it eat them by default ?
if so where to catch it?

Comment: About supers -> seems legit, in `drawRect` and in `initWithFrame` i have those super calls

Comment: Seems like corePlot eats scrolling events I will make a new question about thanks for the answer :)